# Request for suggestion on creating SPSS metadata in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, spss

I work in team where people who are very good in SPSS. Our team believes that SPSS files (SAV files) store more information (metadata more elegantly) than a normal CSV files and wants to stick to SPSS for data management (cleaning, merging, imputing, etc.).

For example, the first image below (data view) stores the data in flat tabular format while second image (variable view) holds more information such as labels, variable type.

I have few questions -

1. I can read the SPSS file in R and then use tidyverse to modify it. But can I create metadata (image 2) and export the data back in SPSS format.
2. Can you please suggest course or book, which can introduce me to working with SPSS data in R

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check Out sjlabelled, expss. I love them
https://github.com/strengejacke/sjlabelled
https://gdemin.github.io/expss/